# Overleaf: Bibliography not appearing

Tags: bibliographies

I have copied and pasted the example here: 
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX#The_bibliography_file

I have created a file "example.tex"

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's 
book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and a file "sample.bib"

```latex
@article{einstein,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
    volume = "322",
    number = "10",
    pages = "891--921",
    year = "1905",
    DOI = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords = "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
    title = {The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author = {Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn = {9780198520115},
    series = {International series of monographs on physics},
    year = {1981},
    publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author = "Donald Knuth",
    title = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url  = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    addendum = "(accessed: 01.09.2016)",
    keywords = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = "1973",
    chapter = "1.2",
    keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
```

when I run it I am getting this output:

> "You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way."

and no bibliography is showing.

Comment: any question here means that something is wrong with overleaf or explanations. With all respect of what you have achieved complain to overleaf and tell them to redo their homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{sample.bib}

% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's 
book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 


\ifCLASSOPTIONcaptionsoff
  \newpage
\fi

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample.bib}

\end{document}
```

The output: "The references will be in a separate page"
[image]

[image]

Comment: this worked, still dont understand why the recommended package from overleaf doesn't. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Type proper in reference.bib file . Do not miss any parenthesis or comma

```
@article{Yasahan2019Roted_object,
title = {Towards Scale-Aware Rotated
Object Detection in Aerial Imagery},
author = {Yasahan,wang and Yue, Zhang,and YI Zhang and Liangjin zhao and Xian,Sun and Guo},
year = "2019",
month = November,
day = "28",
doi = "10.1109/ACCESS.2019.2956569",
language = "English",
volume = "7",
pages = "173855-173865",
journal = "IEEE explore",
publisher = "IEEE",
}
```

and use package

```
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!